# how can i restore the backup.py plugin data of errbot running in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, errbot

I'm running errbot in a docker container, we did the !backup and we have the backup.py, but when i start the docker container it just run /app/venv/bin/run.sh
but i cannot pass -r /srv/backup.py to have all my data restored.

any ideas?

all the data is safe since the /srv is a mounted volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best if you run Errbot in a container is to run it with a real database for the persistence (redis for example).

Then you can simply run `backup.py` from anywhere (including your dev machine).

Even better, you can just do a backup of your redis directly.

Comment: I did not find any data on how to use redis as a backend for the errbot